# Probleme with create view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, syntax, relational-database

Can you help me solve this problem? I'm just a beginner with Microsoft SQL Server and I tried to create a view as I always did in Oracle.

But it causes an error "syntax near the keyword select", I don't understand. Please help me and tell me how we should create a view in SQL Server :

This is the query :

```
CREATE VIEW commandefournisseur 
    SELECT  
        F_LOT.LT_IDENT AS LOT_IDENT
        , ISNULL(SUM(LCF_PRIXTOTAL),0) AS PRIX_HT
        , .LCF_LICENCE AS AVENANT
        , LCF_TAUXTVA AS TAUXTVA
        , CF_ETAT AS COTATION
        , FF_CODE_DEVISE AS CODE_DEVISE
        , BPA_NOM_1 AS BATIMENT
        , BPA_ADRESSE_1 AS Adresse
        , ISNULL (SUM(FF_SOLDE),0) as Reste
        , FF_DATE as dateFact
    FROM 
        F_LIGNECOMFOU
    INNER JOIN 
        F_COMMANDEFOU ON CF_NUMERO = LCF_CF_NUMERO
    INNER JOIN 
        F_LOT ON LCF_LT_IDENT = LT_IDENT
    INNER JOIN 
        F_P_FOURNISSEUR ON CF_IDENT_FO = FOU_IDENT
    INNER JOIN 
        F_FACTURESFOU ON FOU_IDENT = FF_IDENT_FO
    INNER JOIN 
        P_PERSONNE ON FOU_BPP_IDENT = BPP_IDENT
    INNER JOIN 
        P_ADRESSE ON BPA_BPP_IDENT = BPP_IDENT
    WHERE 
        LCF_CODE_AFF = '15330-00' 
        AND LT_CODE IN ('S82')
    GROUP BY 
        LT_IDENT, LCF_LICENCE, LCF_TAUXTVA, CF_ETAT, 
        FF_CODE_DEVISE, BPA_NOM_1, BPA_ADRESSE_1, FF_DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the keyword 'AS' after the view_name

```
CREATE VIEW commandefournisseur 
AS
SELECT ....
```

Please check view syntax [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187956.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You have missed `AS` keyword.

Below is the standard syntax used to create view in SQL Server.

**SQL Server CREATE VIEW syntax**

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

In your case

```
CREATE VIEW commandefournisseur AS
    SELECT  
        F_LOT.LT_IDENT AS LOT_IDENT
        , ISNULL(SUM(LCF_PRIXTOTAL),0) AS PRIX_HT
        , .LCF_LICENCE AS AVENANT
        , LCF_TAUXTVA AS TAUXTVA
        , CF_ETAT AS COTATION
        , FF_CODE_DEVISE AS CODE_DEVISE
        , BPA_NOM_1 AS BATIMENT
        , BPA_ADRESSE_1 AS Adresse
        , ISNULL (SUM(FF_SOLDE),0) as Reste
        , FF_DATE as dateFact
    FROM 
        F_LIGNECOMFOU
    INNER JOIN 
        F_COMMANDEFOU ON CF_NUMERO = LCF_CF_NUMERO
    INNER JOIN 
        F_LOT ON LCF_LT_IDENT = LT_IDENT
    INNER JOIN 
        F_P_FOURNISSEUR ON CF_IDENT_FO = FOU_IDENT
    INNER JOIN 
        F_FACTURESFOU ON FOU_IDENT = FF_IDENT_FO
    INNER JOIN 
        P_PERSONNE ON FOU_BPP_IDENT = BPP_IDENT
    INNER JOIN 
        P_ADRESSE ON BPA_BPP_IDENT = BPP_IDENT
    WHERE 
        LCF_CODE_AFF = '15330-00' 
        AND LT_CODE IN ('S82')
    GROUP BY 
        LT_IDENT, LCF_LICENCE, LCF_TAUXTVA, CF_ETAT, 
        FF_CODE_DEVISE, BPA_NOM_1, BPA_ADRESSE_1, FF_DATE
```